# Mounting GoFlex NAS in Ubuntu fails with Permission denied from fstab only

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, mount, nas

I can mount a NAS from Ubuntu from the command line with:

sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.110/GoFlex\ Home\ Public /media/goflex -o user=,pass=

However, when I add the following line to /etc/fstab:

//192.168.0.110/GoFlex\040Home\040Public /media/goflex/ cifs user=,pass=

and run:

sudo mount -a

I get:

mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

I searched for hours for similar problems and found many suggestions for additional arguments which include: _netdev,uid=1000,gid=1000,noperm,sec=ntlmv2,forceuid,forcegid
but none of them helped.

Any other ideas/suggestions?

Thanks,
Tom